# .Net dll created via IKVM is not showing any namespace in Visual Studio's Object Explorer

Tags: java, .net, dll, jar, ikvm

I have created a simple class in JAVA, created its jar, and converted jar to dll via IKVM version **7.2.4630.5**. I added its reference and also added IKVM.OpenJDK.Core.dll reference to the project to the project but I am getting the following error:

[image]

following is my java class:

[image]

What I am doing wrong?